# Using pairwise_distances_chunked to compute nearest neighbor search

Tags: python, scikit-learn, distance, nearest-neighbor

I have a long skinny data matrix (size: 250,000 x 10), which I will denote `X`. I also have a vector `p` measuring the quality of my data points. My goal is to compute the following function for each row `x` in my data matrix `X`:

r(x) = min{ ||x-y|| | p[y]>p[x], y in X }

On a smaller dataset, what I would use `sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances` to precompute distances, like so:

```
from sklearn import metrics
n = len(X);

D_full = metrics.pairwise_distances(X);
r = np.zeros((n,1));
for i in range(n):
    r[i] = (D_full[i,p>p[i]]).min();
```

However, the above approach is memory-expensive, since I need to store `D_full`: a full n x n matrix. It seems like `sklearn.metrics.pairwise_distances_chunked` could be a good tool for this sort of problem since the distance matrix is only stored one chunk at a time. I was hoping to get some assistance in how to use it though, as I'm currently unfamiliar with generator objects. Suppose I call the following:

```
from sklearn import metrics
D = metrics.pairwise_distances_chunked(X);
D_chunk = next(D)
```

The above code yields `D` (a generator object) and `D_chunk` (a 536 x n array). Does `D_chunk`correspond to the first 536 rows of the matrix `D_full` from my earlier approach? If so, does `next(D_chunk)` correspond to the next 536 rows?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a outline of a possible solution, but details are missing. In short, I would do the following:

Create a `BallTree` to query, and initialise `min_quality_distance` of size 250000 with say zeros.

for `k=2`

1. For each vector, find the closest `k` neighbour (including itself).
2. If vector with most distance within `k` found, has sufficient quality, update `min_quality_distance` for that point.
3. For remaining, repeat with `k=k+1`

In each iteration, we have to query less vectors. The idea is that in each iteration you nibble a few nearest neighbors with the right condition away, and it will be easier with every step. (50% easier?) I will show how to do the first iteration, and with this is should be possible to build the loop.

You can do;

```
import numpy as np
size = 250000

X = np.random.random( size=(size,10))
p = np.random.random( size=size)
```

And create a BallTree with

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree

tree = BallTree(X, leaf_size=10, metric='minkowski')
```

and query it for first iteration with (this will take about 5 minutes.)

```
k_nearest = 2

distances, indici = tree.query(X, k=k_nearest, return_distance=True, dualtree=False, sort_results=True)
```

The indici of most far away point within the nearest `k` is

```
most_far_away_indici = indici[:,-1:]
```

And its quality

```
p[most_far_away_indici]
```

So we can

```
quality_closeby = p[most_far_away_indici]
```

And check if it is sifficient with

```
indici_sufficient_quality = quality_closeby > np.expand_dims(p, axis=1)
```

And we have

```
found_closeby = np.all( indici_sufficient_quality, axis=1 )
```

Which is True is we have found a sufficient quality nearby.

We can update the vector with

```
distances_nearby = distances[:,-1:]

rx = np.zeros(size)
rx[found_closeby] = distances_nearby[found_closeby][:,0]
```

And we now need to take care for the remaining where we were unlucky, these are

```
~found_closeby
```

so

```
indici_not_found = ~found_closeby
```

and

```
distances, indici = tree.query(X[indici_not_found], k=3, return_distance=True, dualtree=False, sort_results=True)
```

etc..

I am sure the first few loops will take minutes, but after a few iterations the speeds will quickly go to seconds.

It is a little exercise with `np.argwhere()` etc to make sure the right indicis get updates.

It might not be the fastest, but it is a workable approach.

Answer (score 0):

Since one cannot know the dimensions of some chunk, I suggest using np.ones_like instead of np.zeros.